# How to get right output of stack sorting

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void sortStack (stack <int>& s){

    int tempVal;
    int topElement;

    if (s.size()<2){
    return;
    }

    else{
        topElement=s.top();
        s.pop();


        if(topElement < s.top()){
            s.push(topElement);
            return;
            } 

        else {
            tempVal=s.top();
            s.top()= topElement;
            topElement=tempVal;
            sortStack (s); 
            s.push(topElement);
            }  
    }  
}


int main (int argc, char * argv[]){

    try {    
        ifstream inFS;
        int fileNumbers;
        stack <int> s;


        if(argc < 2){
           throw runtime_error ("an error occured: no input file name given");
        }

        inFS.open (argv[1]);
        string fileName = argv[1];

        if (!inFS.is_open()){
            throw runtime_error ("an error occured: could not open input file " + fileName);
        }

        while (inFS >> fileNumbers){
            s.push(fileNumbers); 
            sortStack(s);   
        }

        for (int i=0; i<=s.size(); i++){
          cout << s.top() << " ";  
          s.pop();

        }  

        inFS.close();
    }

    catch (runtime_error & excpt){
        cout << excpt.what() << endl;
    }


return 0;    
}
```

I want to sort numbers from a file in a stack. It has to be a stack and it has to be done with recursion. The numbers in the file are: 4 8 10 3 6 5. It works very well except for the last 2 elements. Thus my output is : 3 4 5 6. It does not sort 8 and 10 as well. Id I do s.size+4 in the for loop it works, but then it doesnot work if I have just one number in the file. Why is that happening???

Comment: A good tool for find out "what is happening" is a debugger.  A debugger allows you to single step execution and look at the values of variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: how to debug with c++?

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: Depends on your platform and toolset.  Visual Studio has an excellent debugger.  Linux has `gdb`.  You can set up Eclipse with `gdb` or another debugging tool.

Comment: I use VS Code . I tried to debug it say launch program does not exist

Comment: You are sorting the stack after each push. You should fill your stack, sort it once and print it.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug

Comment: so where i Should the push function?

Comment: Is this a thing? Sorting a stack? It seems like the least-suited data structure to me.

Comment: @sweenish It's more of an academic question. To learn about algorithms.

Comment: I'd say the approach is wrong, then. Use a list or a queue or a vector. Those all have much stronger use-cases for being sorted than a stack. The stack just gets in the way of sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your output procedure:

```
    for (int i=0; i <= s.size(); i++) {
        cout << s.top() << " ";  
        s.pop();
    }
```

You compare `i` with the stack size, but you decrease it's size popping the elements. The correct code is:

```
    while (s.size()) {
        cout << s.top() << " ";  
        s.pop();
    }
```